# get s3 bucket files along with permissions

Tags: r, amazon-s3

Is there a way to list permission(read/write) of all files in a bucket through R along with files list?

THis below code will list all the files

```
get_bucket("mycollection",prefix="collfolder")

#Output

collfolder/2016_random.jpg
collfolder/audio
```

Comment: AWS S3 doesn't have a notion of read/write permission like in a OS file system. Do you mean reading bucket policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using `aws.s3` package. If so get the Access Control List (ACL) for each object:

```
get_acl(object, bucket, ...)
```

More info in [the docs](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/aws.s3.pdf).